# How can I pass all the variables as a list and download multiple csv with few lines of code instead of several lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have around 50 stocks for which I need to pass the variable ticker1, ticker2, ticker3.....ticker50 in the URL. Currently, I wrote a repetitive 50 URLs where I pass Tickers from ticker1, ticker2...ticker50 seperately. How can I acheieve it without repeating the lines of code?

So intead of having url1...url2....url50, I have one single url where it loops in all the tickers for ticker1-50 and it retrieves/downloads multiple csv in a given path.

Below is my repetitive code which achieves the result but i want to optimize it and make it clutter free.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
 
# Stk 1

    ticker1 = 'AAPL'
    period1Stk1 = int(time.mktime(now.replace(now.year - 1).timetuple()))
    period2Stk2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 59).timetuple()))
    interval1 = '1d'
    url1 = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker1}?period1={period1Stk1}&period2={period2Stk2}&interval={interval1}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'

# Stk 2
ticker2 = 'ADBE'
period1Stk1 = int(time.mktime(now.replace(now.year - 1).timetuple()))
period2Stk2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 59).timetuple()))
interval1 = '1d'
url2 = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker2}?period1={period1Stk1}&period2={period2Stk2}&interval={interval1}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'

retrieve(url1,'/Users/stocks/Cypto/AAPL.csv')
retrieve(url2,'/Users/stocks/ADBE.csv')
```

Thanks and appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple version of your loop, that should download into same folder

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
period1Stk1 = int(time.mktime(now.replace(now.year - 1).timetuple()))
period2Stk2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 59).timetuple()))
interval1 = '1d'

tickers = ['AAPL', 'ADBE']

for ticker in tickers:
    url = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={period1Stk1}&period2={period2Stk2}&interval={interval1}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'
    retrieve(url,'/Users/stocks/{0}.csv'.format(ticker))
```

Comment: Thank you so much crayxt! Worked perfectly fine. Appreciate your quick turnaround!